# How to use the POST command to send a file?

Tags: http, command-line, post

I would like to send a file using the POST command available on almost all linuxes which include Perl.

I'm wondering how..

i would like to do something like :

```
linux:currentdir/$ POST http://www.example.com/upload.php > myFileToUpload
```

I guess i had probably to encode the file, i'm right, it's in base64 ? Isn't it ?
I also read in the man that i'm able to set the Content-Type header, should it be set with 'multipart/mixed' ?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84619/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl and many others

Comment: You should have read, like i did, it is about cURL, but well, this sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider looking into Curl. It is much more robust. An example of automating a file-upload form submission would be:

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="upload.cgi">
  <input type=file name=upload>
  <input type=submit name=press value="OK">
</form>
```

Then use the command

```
curl -F upload=@localfilename -F press=OK http://www.example.com/form.cgi
```

Comment: thank you, i didn't really know about curl until know.
Sounds interesting.